# SQL Server CmdExec Job Step Doesn't Delete Files

Tags: sql-server, cmd, delete-file, database-backups

I have a SQL job with a CmdExec step which is supposed to delete historic files from a network location.  I have a Credential set up called BackupJob which has the Administrator account as its identity, and a proxy called BackupProxy, which uses this credential.

My command, which runs as BackupProxy, is as follows:

```
net use Z: \\GSA-NAS-P1\Public
forfiles /p "Z:\SQL Server Backups\Prod_DB1" /m *.* /c "cmd /c del @file"  /d -15
net use Z: /d
```

The step completes successfully but the files remain.  If I run this from the command line whilst logged in as Administrator, the files are deleted.  Also, the Z: drive doesn't disconnect.

I have prior steps in this job that also run under the BackupProxy and they work correctly.  Can anyone tell what's going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the `net use` was successful? There is no error checking.

Comment: Hm, perhaps not.  It might have been mapped from when I ran it from the command line.  It's not mapped after running the job.  So either it's not working at all, or it's mapping and deleting in an instant.

Another note:  I already have the network path mapped permanently as Q, but when I simply used this path in the `forfiles` command, it said the path could not be found.  That's why I decided to map Z.